# Something "clicking" figuratively

Tags: vocabulaire, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques, anglicismes

Je cherche un moyen de dire que quelque chose "clicks" dans le sens où « je le comprends très bien tout à coup ». Par exemple, je voudrais le dire dans les contextes suivants:

> Something about this code just isn't **clicking** for me.

> And all of a sudden it **clicked** and I knew exactly what to do.

etc.

Qu'en pensez-vous ?

Comment: On peut penser à « coller ». *Quelque chose dans ce code ne colle pas pour moi*. *À présent tout collait et je savais exactement quoi faire*. C'est peut être pas une solution universelle, mais dans ces deux cas ça marche plutôt bien.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Je n'utiliserais pas la même expression française dans chacun de tes exemples.

[*Faire tilt*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/faire_tilt) convient bien en général pour cet emploi de "click". On y retrouve l'analogie avec le bruit (même si « tilt » n'implique pas seulement le bruit).

- Et tout à coup ça a fait tilt et j'ai su quoi faire.

Mais je trouve que « faire tilt » passe mal à la forme négative. Je préférerais dire :

- « Il y a quelque chose qui m'échappe dans ce code. »
- Ou plus familièrement : « Il y a quelque chose que je ne pige pas dans ce code. »

« [Piger](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/piger) » passe aussi à la forme affirmative, mais avec « piger » on perd de la soudaineté qu'on a dans « faire tilt ».

On a aussi l'expression « avoir le déclic » (ou ne pas l'avoir). C'est moins familier que « faire tilt ».

- J'ai soudain eu le déclic et j'ai su quoi faire.

Mais là aussi j'ai du mal à le mettre à la forme négative et je préfère « ça m'échappe ».

---

**Edit**

As mentioned in @Sardine comment, [*percuter*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/percuter) is another good alternative

- Il y a quelque chose sur lequel je ne percute pas avec ce code.
- Soudain j'ai percuté et j'ai su comment faire.

Comment: Super c'est parfait merci

Comment: Il y a aussi _Eureka_.

Comment: @Frank Il me semble que ce n'est pas ce qui est demandé dans la question. C'est une interjection, pas un verbe. En anglais c'est aussi [eureka](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eureka),

Comment: @None L'OP cherche _un moyen de dire que quelque chose "clicks"_, mais oui, c'est plus éloigné.

Comment: On pourrait rajouter "percuter": ça ne percute pas = ça rentre par une oreille et ressort par l'autre. Je précise pour les anglophones que "tilt" ici est par association au jeu de flipper et n'a aucun rapport avec la notion d'inclinaison (autre qu'à travers le fait que le jeu se braque s'il est trop secoué).

Comment: @Sardine _ça ne percute pas_: c'est une nouvelle tournure parmi les djeuns à Paris? Je connaissais _il ne percute pas_, qui n'est pas un compliment.

Comment: @Frank Effectivement, c'est une tournure familière. Le wiktionaire  https://fr.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/percuter donne l'exemple de percuter et de ne pas percuter, avec ce sens du moment où la compréhension a lieu (à l'image de percuter, un contact instantané). Je lui trouve un air d'argot (imagé) mais c'est peut-être plus récent, les exemples ne vont que jusqu'à 2010. "Il ne percute pas" = il ne fait pas grande impression?

Comment: @Frank DCLF : « fam. Comprendre, réagir de manière à manifester une compréhension. *Il n'a pas percuté* ». Les exemples les plus anciens que je trouve sont de la fin du XXe siècle. Trouvé via google books : ( *Dominique Voynet : une vraie nature*, Murielle Szac · 1998) « ... il intègre et enregistre les préoccupations environnementalistes des Verts  mais, sur les grandes options écolos [...] Jospin ne percute pas.  » Bien sûr, au XXI on trouve beaucoup d'exemples.

Comment: @Sardine "Il ne percute pas celui-là" = il n'est pas très intelligent, si je me souviens bien.